# Asynchronous autocomplete in winforms

Tags: winforms, autocomplete

Is there a way to get asynchronous auto-complete in a Winforms TextBox or ComboBox?  AJAX is so nice, and I would be amazed if the .NET framework doesn't have a thick client equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such feature out of the box, but it shouldn't be too hard to implement it yourself... Handle the `TextChanged` event, send a request asynchronously to get the matching items, and change the `AutoCompleteSource` when you get the result. You just need to be careful to access UI components on the UI thread, using the `Invoke` method (or you can use a `BackgroundWorker` and access the UI in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event)

Answer (score 1):

I have written an async autocomplete class for a TextBox:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TextboxAutocomplete
{
    public abstract class AutoCompleteSource
    {
        private TextBox mTextBox;
        private AutoCompleteMode mAutoCompleteMode;

        public AutoCompleteSource(TextBox textbox) :
            this(textbox, AutoCompleteMode.Suggest) { }

        public AutoCompleteSource(TextBox textbox, AutoCompleteMode mode)
        {
            if (textbox == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("textbox");

            if (textbox.IsDisposed)
                throw new ArgumentException("textbox");

            mTextBox = textbox;
            mAutoCompleteMode = mode;

            mTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.None;

            BackgroundWorker autoCompleteLoader = new BackgroundWorker();
            autoCompleteLoader.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(autoCompleteLoader_DoWork);
            autoCompleteLoader.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(autoCompleteLoader_RunWorkerCompleted);
            autoCompleteLoader.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void autoCompleteLoader_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = e.Result as AutoCompleteStringCollection;
            if (collection == null) return;

            if (mTextBox.InvokeRequired)
            {
                mTextBox.Invoke(new SetAutocompleteSource(DoSetAutoCompleteSource), new object[] { collection });
            }
            else
            {
                DoSetAutoCompleteSource(collection);
            }
        }

        protected void DoSetAutoCompleteSource(AutoCompleteStringCollection collection)
        {
            if (mTextBox.IsDisposed) return;

            mTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = mAutoCompleteMode;
            mTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            mTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
        }

        void autoCompleteLoader_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> autoCompleteItems = GetAutocompleteItems();
            if (autoCompleteItems == null) return;
            AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            collection.AddRange(GetAutocompleteItems().ToArray());
            e.Result = collection;
        }

        protected abstract List<string> GetAutocompleteItems();
    }

    internal delegate void SetAutocompleteSource(AutoCompleteStringCollection collection);
}
```

Sample implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace TextboxAutocomplete
{
    class MockAutoCompleteSource : AutoCompleteSource
    {
        public MockAutoCompleteSource(TextBox textbox)
            : base(textbox)
        {

        }

        protected override List<string> GetAutocompleteItems()
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2500; i++)
            {
                result.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
 ...
 TextBox myTextbox = new TextBox();
 MockAutoCompleteSource autoComplete =
      new MockAutoCompleteSource(myTextbox);
 ...
```

Comment: But the autocomplete should happen asynchronously when text is changed. How is it hooked to the text_changed event?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I know that in MFC you can use [SHAutoComplete](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2007/11/01/adding-autocomplete-to-your-edit-controls.aspx) and the shell will do it for you. However I'm not sure the best way to do this in WinForms, but it should be possible.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524166/autocomplete-textbox-with-features-of-like-clause-example-hello-c-windows) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524166/autocomplete-textbox-with-features-of-like-clause-example-hello-c-windows) for some more info.