# Autocomplete [contains instead of starting with] in winform TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

```
// [in designer] textBoxInContext.AutoCompleteMode = Suggest
// [in designer] textBoxInContext.AutoCompleteSource = CustomSource
AutoCompleteStringCollection autoComplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
autoComplete.AddRange(myArrayofStrings);
textBoxInContext.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoComplete;
```

I have this code which works well as documented in MSDN. 
 
 Problem: if user types "PS" it shows all the string starting with "PS"; I would like to display all the strings containing "PS"

Any pointers ?

Comment: This should be a fairly simple task to achieve but we'd need to see more of your code to pinpoint the line to change. something like `var results = autoComplete.Where(x => x.StartsWith("PS");` becomes `var results = autoComplete.Where(x => x.Contains("PS");`

Comment: @JLevett : that's all the code. I am trying to use auto complete feature provided by MS. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx]

Comment: You might have a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524166/autocomplete-textbox-with-features-of-like-clause-example-hello-c-sharp-window] from the "related links" section on the right - looks like this behaviour is hardly possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find another way, I suggest doing it manually:

1. Use a combobox with no items(you'll fill them manually later).
2. Have a string array with your possible suggestions.
3. At the `combobox.TextChanged` or `KeyUp` event take its text and compare it to your string array whichever way you want and, after clearing the `combobox.Items`, add the found results to the `combobox.Items` and make sure to set the `DroppedDown` property to true if you have found suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The stupid but fun suggestion: make a class that inherits from AutoCompleteStringCollection and play with it in debug to see if you can fake this out.

The normal suggestion: make your own autocomplete with a listbox.